# How to insert tabs \t in a listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, listbox

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()

name = 'Jeff'

dob = '01/01/2000'

gender = 'male'

text = str(name)+'\t'+str(dob)+'\t'+str(gender)

Lb = Listbox(root)
Lb.insert(0, text)
Lb.pack()

Lb.selection_set(0)

root.mainloop()
```

When this code is run, it displays the name then dob then male like it was asked, but it doesn't display tabs between them. I know there is a easy solution by just inserting finger spaces instead of tabs, but this is apart of a larger project and finger spaces will make the code incredibly awkward and inefficient to deal with. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution using Tk itself, but you could try using `spacer.join([name, dob, gender])` where you've set `spacer` to a string of 4 or 8 spaces. Also, calling `str(s)` where `s` is already a string doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I don't quite understand, how would I implement 'spacer.join'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research, I have learned that if you want to insert a tab \t into a tkinter listbox, it will not work on a Windows OS, I do not know why...

I have managed to find a solution created previosuly by [wiffleball687](https://www.reddit.com/user/wiffleball687) from [www.reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/19ek6b/tab_character_not_rendering_in_tkinter_listbox/).

```
import tkinter

def tabify(s, tabsize = 4):
    ln = ((len(s)/tabsize)+1)*tabsize
    return s.ljust(ln)

rt = tkinter.Tk()
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(rt, font = 'Courier') #change to a fixed width font
listbox.pack()
listbox.insert(tkinter.END, tabify('a') + 'b')
rt.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to insert a tab in a listbox is exactly how you are doing it. You just happen to be inserting data that aligns with the tabstops. To see what I mean, add the following line to your code:

```
Lb.insert("end", "1\t2\t3\t4\t5")
```

You will see that the date and the word "male" line up exactly with some of the tabstops. Unfortunately you cannot configure the tabstops in a listbox.

[image]

If you need configurable tabstops, you'll have to simulate a listbox using a `Text` widget with some custom bindings.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to add an image. When I insert this line you suggested, it doesn't do any tabstops... it does "Jeff01/01/2000male" and "12345" without any tabstops.

Comment: 'from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()

name = 'Jeff'

dob = '01/01/2000'

gender = 'male'

text = str(name)+'\t'+str(dob)+'\t'+str(gender)

Lb = Listbox(root)
Lb.insert(0, text)
Lb.insert("end", "1\t2\t3\t4\t5")
Lb.pack()

Lb.selection_set(0)

root.mainloop()'

Comment: Sorry again, I must learn how to format this properly, have I done something wrong or misinterpreted your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Is there a way I can show you a picture? Or could it be different versions of Python?

Comment: I have just learned tabs in a listbox works for mac OS, but will not render / display correctly in Windows...        [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/19ek6b/tab_character_not_rendering_in_tkinter_listbox/)

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that there is any way to have this functionality in your Tkinter GUIs for now.

After some research I have found a way to format text in a GUI using a **Text** widget.

However, I was unsuccessful in an attempt to use this widget in a **Listbox**.

Here is a simple sample of code to demo the use of a `Text` widget.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

root = Tk()

name = 'Jeff'
dob = '01/01/2000'
gender = 'male'

text = Text(root, height = 2, width = 30)
text.insert(END, str(name)+'\t'+str(dob)+'\t'+str(gender))
text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I tried to insert the widget `Text` into a Listbox like you have above in your code I got this result.

[image: Attempt to use a Text widget in a Listbox using Tkinter]

I hope that this was helpful and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Comment: Thank you, this does help however I was aiming for a listbox because the user can select and highlight rows within it without changing the text. Although, I am sure I could attempt to implement your method into a listbox in different ways. I'll just have to keep having a stab at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tkinter is not the best GUI programming interface to use. It's functionality shows it's limits in many places :/

Comment: Unfortunately I have learned that also but when too late into my project. But for next time, what interface Python library would you recommend?

Comment: While I haven't personally used it I have seen many good UIs developed with [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home).